# Invoke Rest API using Oauth 2.0 token in logstash http output plugin

Tags: oauth-2.0, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am trying to publish log events to my rest API using `logstash` `http output` plugin. It works if there is no authorization or I enable the basic authentication But my requirement is to invoke the API using `Oauth 2.0` access tokens. When I specify the `Authorization header` with access token I am getting `401` error. From `SOAPUI` I have tested token is working fine. Below are the logstash configs.

```
output {



    if [type] == "error" {  

        if "loglevelerror" in [tags] {

            #*******************************************************************

            #                 Sending Messages to EventAPI

            #*******************************************************************

            http {

                url => "http://serverip:8281/events"

                headers => {

                    "Authorization" => "Bearer c505e8f7-ecb3-346f-8216-f906965edc17"

                    "RequestSource" => "agent"

                    "Accept" => "application/json"

                }

        connect_timeout => 60

        socket_timeout => 60

                http_method => "post"

                format => "json"

                mapping => [my mappings]



            }

        }

    }

}
```

Any help would be a great favour.

Comment: It seems like this question (and the answer) may be also be heavily dependent on what "[your] rest API" is doing an possibly how your Oauth 2.0 provider is configured and/or differences things between the source and destination. Ex. is there something in between them such as whitelists on a firewall that is being tripped up by an unexpected user-agent value? That's just an example of "it works on one tool but not the other" kind of thing that can be hard to pin down.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But another thing is: Does logstash support the oauth2.0?